# Masuda Method Help

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I've recently just completed the National Pokedex (YAY) and I thought I would get into shiny hunting/collecting or whatever. I know that one of the breeding pokemon has to be foreign, but can they BOTH be foreign, or will it not work? Also, does having the Shiny Charm improve your chances of hatching a shiny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming from Bulbapedia:

> The Masuda method involves breeding two Pokémon created in games of different countries. An Egg resulting from such a pairing will have a higher likelihood of being Shiny. The most common way to arrange such a pairing is to use one foreign Pokémon and one from the game in which the breeding occurs, although the method will work in any game provided at least one of the Pokémon in the pair is from a country different to the country of the game cartridge.
>
> If both Pokémon are foreign to the cartridge but are both from the same country, then the Masuda method will not take effect.

Concerning the Shiny Charm:

> If the player has the Shiny Charm, the game will make two further attempts to generate a Shiny Pokémon, bringing the total chance up to 1/1024 or eight times more likely than normal.

Hope that helped.

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method

Comment: @Triforce_Rapidash - you should mark Jonathan's answer as accepted if it answers your question. Click the green checkmark underneath the vote count :)